# Как задать условие?

Tags: java, android

Есть некий Edit Text надо задать ему условие что если прописаны 3 букы стартовал My methoв; а если поле сново будет пустым то вернулся в начальное положение

Comment: Мне кажется, вам следует: 1) почитать какие-нибудь начального уровня книжки по программированию; 2) постараться тщательнее продумывать и формулировать свои вопросы

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий, но как то один толковый программист мне сказал изучить Ява по книжкам  невозможно.твремя и только практика .и он был прав ,да я читаю 2 книги 1)Ява полное руководство 8-ое издание 2)Библиотека Ява проффесионалов

Comment: но всеже брежь есть у всего и у вся никто не может сказать что недопускал примитивных ошибок или базовых глупостей))я чтото изучил чтото еще надо изучать )все отдается сравнению )благодарю за ваш комментарий ю

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               if (charSequence.length() == 3){
                   // здесь вызывыете My method
               } 
               if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
                   // здесь возвращаетесь в начальное состояние
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: спасибо впервые увидел этот слушатель .а воше так много слушателей, есть гдето их клаасификация?с удовольствием почиталбы о них

Comment: @elik Ваш толковый программист не сказал вам, помимо сомнительного совета не читать книжки, что есть такая **официальная документация**, в которой указаны ВСЕ возможные классы и интерфейсы фреймворка Android. В частности [интерфейсы класса `View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#nestedclasses), от которого наследуется `EditText` или метод класса `TextView` (от которого так же наследуется `EditText`) - [`addTextChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)).

Comment: @elik Если у вас есть какие то мысли по поводу определенного класса, но вы не знаете, как их реализовать - начать стоит не с написания вопроса,  а с изучения документации по этому классу и классов выше его по иерархии наследования. Там вы в полной мере проникнитесь всей класификацией.